# Hash map iteration

Tags: iterator, hashmap

How do I iterate through a  hash map to find the first 10 elements  for eg if my map contains string as key and int as value, I want to fetch the first 10 values with highest integer?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be great if you show us what you've attempted, it will give us the opportunity to push you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have `Map` and we are allowed to use external library - [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Maps.newTreeMap();
        map.put("A", 13);
        map.put("B", 11);
        map.put("C", 27);
        map.put("D", 38);
        map.put("E", 25);
        map.put("F", 12);
        map.put("G", 25);
        map.put("D", 35);
        map.put("H", 28);
        map.put("R", 13);
        map.put("N", 24);
        map.put("T", 37);
```

Create Guava `MultiMap` and add entries from original `map`

```
  Multimap<String, Integer> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
      for(String key : map.keySet()){
          multiMap.put(key, map.get(key));
      }
```

Inverse `multiMap` and copy to `TreeMultiMap`

```
  TreeMultimap<Integer, String> reversed = TreeMultimap.create();
  Multimaps.invertFrom(multiMap, reversed);
```

Create `List` from entries and get first 10 elements:

```
Lists.newArrayList(reversed.entries()).subList(0,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time thing, you can sort the HashMap by converting to a List then back to a LinkedHashMap:

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", 13);
    map.put("B", 11);
    map.put("C", 27);
    map.put("D", 38);
    map.put("E", 25);
    map.put("F", 12);
    map.put("G", 25);
    map.put("D", 35);
    map.put("H", 28);
    map.put("R", 13);
    map.put("N", 24);
    map.put("T", 37);

    // Take a List copy of the Map
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());

    // Sort the list by the Value
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    // Create new Map (use LinkedHashMap to maintain order)
    Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Most HashMaps don`t preserve any kind of order so you might need to read all the keys, sort them and then get the corresponding values from the Hash. If you can tell us what language and provide some sample code, someone might be able to help further.

Comment: Ok, so the same logic applies. Just have to sort the values instead of the keys ...